# Sql echo row with php

Tags: php, sql

I can connect to DB but i cant echo , all time that said 0 results but my DB have TABLE (text) with 2 COLUMN id and text and i have inserted text in my table.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","1078362","nenaddurmisi022");

if (!$con) {

die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());


}


$sql = "SELECT vesti FROM comment";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

// output data of each row

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo  $row["vesti"]."<br>";

}

} 

else {

echo "0 results";

}



    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: FYI: `text` is a column type in MySQL and really should not be used as the name of a table or column... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html  MySQL won't stop you and actually allows stuff like this... `create table text (text text);`

Comment: I have created new table which name is table and that table have 2 column id(num,Auto Increment) vesti(varchar255) and i change my code to this
$sql = "SELECT vesti FROM table";
echo $row["vesti"];
and doesn't work

Comment: I strongly recommend not creating a table named `table`. I didn't even know you could do that.

Comment: I renamed table and this is my table
http://postimg.org/image/rwg5n83y3/
and doesn't work.

Comment: OK, try adding `print_r($result);` after your `mysqli_query()` and let us know what that shows.

Comment: Nothing just 0 results.Can i check does code for select work?

Comment: Are you sure there's data in that table? Do you have MySQL Workbench or PHPMyAdmin or something like that you can use to check the contents of the table?

Comment: I using PHPMyAdmin 
http://postimg.org/image/shkgbcfz7/

Comment: OK, I took a shot at an answer to this.

Comment: Again, doesn't work.Can you try this code on your pc you have my password in code?

Comment: Add the error settings at the end of my answer to the top of your script and be sure to change to `mysqli_close()`. I just edited my answer to include that.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/vhosts/nenadspec.6te.net/display.php on line 14
14 line if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)

Comment: The `mysqli_query()` function returns FALSE on failure, so that's what's happening. Did you make the code changes I listed in my answer?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/r8887133v/

Comment: Hmm, right now I'm stumped. I'll take another look later if you don't have an answer yet.

Comment: I resolve this i changed mysqli to mysql on everything and its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using all `mysqli` functions except for your database connection. Try changing the first line to...

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "1078362", "nenaddurmisi022");
```

...and change the last line to...

```
mysqli_close($con);
```

I'm guessing there are a lot of errors generated by this script, but you're not seeing them. You should add these lines to the top of the script...

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM text";
```

instead of

```
$sql = "SELECT text FROM text";
```

also be sure you'r table name is text.

one last thing you could try is to replace

```
echo  $row["text"]."<br>";
```

by

```
print_r($row);
```

to see if there's a result set from you'r Database

Comment: Doesn't work.Can you try this code on your computer you have my password of database in code?

Comment: you'r database is in your computer,  also i dont have the SQL schema in place.